# Do "alborada", "amanecer", and "madrugada" refer to the same thing?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sinónimos, vocabulario

In English we have the two words "dawn" and "sunrise".

But in Spanish there are three words, "alborada", "amanecer", and "madrugada".

Do the three Spanish words refer to the same thing? Or is one closer to "sunrise" and another close to "dawn"? In which case where would the third fit in?

Comment: Don't forget *la salida del sol* and *el crepúsculo*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Alborada" and "amanecer" are two different words that refer to "sunrise". "Anochecer" and "atardecer" are used for the dusk, but "anochecer" is used near the night, whilst "atardecer" is used in the afternoon.

"Madrugada" is the time between 00.00 and 06.00 aprox.

- [atardecer](http://dle.rae.es/atardecer)
- [anochecer](http://dle.rae.es/anochecer)
- [alborada](http://dle.rae.es/alborada)
- [amanecer](http://dle.rae.es/amanecer)
- [madrugada](http://dle.rae.es/madrugada)

Comment: As far as I know, `anochecer` and `atardecer` are not related to the english word `dawn`. Am I wrong?

Comment: you're right atardecer and anochecer are related to dusk and to get dark (I don't know if there is an specific word?)

Comment: Sorry, I confused 'dawn' with dusk... :\

Comment: I was wondering about the dawn/dusk thing there too.